# SSH : config file not used as I expected

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I recently updated from Trusty (14.04) to Xenial (16.04), and I now have a different behaviour when using ssh, and my `.ssh/config` file.

*Previously:* in the config file, when a first rule would apply on host `a` to change the target `Hostname` from `a` to `b`, and another rule would apply on `b`, the second rule would be applied.

*Now:* only the first rule is applied, the second one is ignored.

Here is a sample of this new behavior:

```
# I added two extra names for "127.0.0.1" :
legec@Workstation[.ssh]$ head -2 /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   foo foo.homesweethome.com

# config file :
legec@Workstation[.ssh]$ cat ~/.ssh/config
# this rule expands "foo" to "foo.homesweethome.com"
Host foo
    Hostname foo.homesweethome.com

# this rule sets default port and user for "foo.homesweethome.com" :
Host foo.homesweethome.com
    Port 2222
    User foobar

# when running ssh :    
legec@Workstation[.ssh]$ ssh -v foo
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
  # as you can see in the following two lines,
  # the first config rule is applied
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/legec/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/legec/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for foo
  # the second rule is skipped
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to foo.homesweethome.com [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.

  [.. extra debug messages about possible keys to present, protocol setup ... ]

debug1: Next authentication method: password
# I was hoping to see a connection on port 2222,
# and asking the password for user foobar :
legec@foo.homesweethome.com's password:
```

The current version of my ssh lib is :

```
legec@Workstation[.ssh]$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

[edit] : As [fkraeim](https://askubuntu.com/a/986493/18501) reminded me, the version of `OpenSSH` in Trusty (14.04) was 6.6 .

#### Questions

- What changed in the behavior of ssh ?
- How can I have both rules apply in the above example?

*Note:* for a more complete context, in my real config file, the configuration looks like:

```
Host bar baz
    Hostname %h.homesweethome.com

Host foo
    Hostname foo.homesweethome.com

Host *.homesweethome.com
    User foobar
    Port 2222
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This a good illustration that sometimes, a person's bug is another person's feature...

This behaviour of OpenSSH in 14.04 is actually a [bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2267) introduced in OpenSSH 6.6 (which is the version in Ubuntu 14.04) and fixed in 6.8 (see also the [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html)). The correct way to do what you want is

```
Host bar baz
    Hostname %h.homesweethome.com

Host foo
    Hostname foo.homesweethome.com

Host foo bar baz *.homesweethome.com
    User foobar
    Port 2222
```

Alternatively, maybe canonicalisation is really what you want... For example

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains homesweethome.com

Host *.homesweethome.com
    User foobar
    Port 2222
```

... could work for you. A difference with your current configuration is that if for example `goo.homesweethome.com` exists, `ssh goo` will try to connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what changed between 14.04 and 16.04, but the `CanonicalizeHostnames` option seems to play a role. From [`man ssh_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html):

```
CanonicalizeHostname
 Controls whether explicit hostname canonicalization is performed.
 The default, “no”, is not to perform any name rewriting and let
 the system resolver handle all hostname lookups.  If set to “yes”
 then, for connections that do not use a ProxyCommand, ssh(1) will
 attempt to canonicalize the hostname specified on the command
 line using the CanonicalDomains suffixes and
 CanonicalizePermittedCNAMEs rules.  If CanonicalizeHostname is
 set to “always”, then canonicalization is applied to proxied
 connections too.

 If this option is enabled, then the configuration files are
 processed again using the new target name to pick up any new
 configuration in matching Host and Match stanzas.
```

Note the last paragraph. And when I add:

```
Host *
  CanonicalizeHostname yes
```

I get the expected result:

```
$ ssh foo                
ssh: connect to host foo.homesweethome.com port 2222: Connection refused
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea to enable `CanonicalizeHostname` just to force a re-parsing; that's certainly not its purpose.